# Is it possible to pass variables to resource action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to pass a variable in destroy action. I tried this.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('18x18/Icon_3.png'), :url => {:action => :destroy, :startup => true}, :rel => "tooltip", :title => t('remove'), class: 'table-icon', method: :delete, data: {confirm: t('care_and_feed_delete_warning')} if can? :destroy, CareAndFeed %>
```

But this is not working. But this is perfectly working

```
<%= link_to image_tag('18x18/Icon_3.png'), @care_and_feed, :rel => "tooltip", :title => t('remove'), class: 'table-icon', method: :delete, data: {confirm: t('care_and_feed_delete_warning')} if can? :destroy, CareAndFeed %>
```

How to make this work?

Comment: you should use url helpers

Comment: Can you show us your corresponding routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<%= link_to image_tag('18x18/Icon_3.png'), your_destroy_path(@care_and_feed, startup: true), :rel => "tooltip", :title => t('remove'), class: 'table-icon', method: :delete, data: {confirm: t('care_and_feed_delete_warning')} if can? :destroy, CareAndFeed %>
```

Hope this helps!